# npm error and proxy server issue

Tags: proxy, npm

I am trying to install few packages like express using npm install command from npm command prompt.
But I am facing issues while doing so. All the packages are giving error.

[error for npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdx4F.png)

By guessing this is a proxy issue,tried adding the npm proxy config’s

```
***$ npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>/ 
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>/***
```

But while checking for the proxy server, getting the below.

```
[Proxy server o/p][2]
```

***C:......>netsh winhttp show proxy
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
    Direct access (no proxy server).***

Please help me in solving this. I am new to npm and not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

1. npm config set strict-ssl false
2. npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
3. npm --proxy http://username:password@proxy...:port_here install packagename